# Orthonormalized Bernstein polynomials using Gram-Schmidt

Tags: finite-element, basis-set, collocation, spectral-method

I was wondering, before trying to do that myself, has anyone attempted to do orthonormalization of Bernstein polynomials using Gram-Schmidt?

I discussed this with several people and have been told that Bernstein polynomials don't make a good basis for FEM because they are not orthogonal.

I didn't use FEM, instead I made a (pseudospectral-like) collocation method formulation, and documented my attempts to solve elliptic problems in 2D domains in [an arXiv article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.3567). I had exponential convergence with polynomial orders $n<20$. After that approximation become worse as $n$ was increased. One of the reasons may be non-orthogonality of Bernstein polynomial basis functions.

The code discussed is [here](http://code.google.com/p/bernstein-poly/).

My idea is to make a new orthogonal basis using Gram-Schmidt and try again.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you asked, but maybe [this paper](http://www.maths.dundee.ac.uk/tgoodman/rida.pdf) is helpful.

Comment: @ChristianClason - That's an answer, as far as I'm concerned, feel free to move it out of comments, and perhaps paste the abstract in to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The paper [1] gives an explicit construction of the Bernstein form of a set of  orthogonal polynomials on simplices based on Legendre polynomials.

[1] [Farouki, R.T., Goodman, T.N.T and Sauer, T: *Construction of orthogonal bases for polynomials in Bernstein form on triangular and simplex domains*, Computer Aided Geometric Design 20 (2003), 209-230, DOI: 10.1016/S0167-8396(03)00025-6](http://www.maths.dundee.ac.uk/tgoodman/rida.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I think Rob Kirby told me once that he had written something on using Bernstein polynomials for FEM. Take a look at his web site at Texas Tech (or now at Baylor).

Comment: Indeed, there are two recent papers in Numerische Mathematik: [121(2): 261 -- 279 (2012)](https://bearspace.baylor.edu/Robert_Kirby/www/papers/bern2.pdf) and [117(4): 631 -- 652 (2011)](https://bearspace.baylor.edu/Robert_Kirby/www/papers/bern1.pdf).